# search code in organization and filter out particular repository

Tags: github

I would like to search in my organization for specific term.
For this purpose I can use:

```
org:my-org searched-term
```

But this shows many code from particular repo which I'm not interested in. So I would like to somehow filter out this repo. I've tried following with no luck:

```
org:my-org -repo-i-want-to-exclude in:name searched-term
org:my-org repo-i-want-to-exclude -in:name searched-term
org:my-org -repo-i-want-to-exclude -in:name searched-term
```

Seems that problem is that I cannot combine both repo name and searched term, this does not work also:

```
org:my-org repo-i-want-to-exclude in:name searched-term
org:my-org searched-term repo-i-want-to-exclude in:name
```

What is correct syntax?